# Unable to clone All-Users after Gerrit move

Tags: git, gerrit

About 2 years ago we moved our Gerrit 2.10 site to a new datacenter, copying over the repos as part of the process. This is probably the first time I've tried to access the "All-Users" repo, and I'm seeing the following error:

```
user@desktop=> git clone ssh://user@gerrit.whoi.edu:29418/All-Users
Cloning into 'All-Users'...
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

Other repos aren't experiencing this issue. Is there some way I can troubleshoot and remediate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to ***Gerrit*** > ***BROWSE*** > ***Repositories*** > ***All-Users*** > ***Branches*** and check if the HEAD is pointing to "refs/meta/config". Correct if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a Gerrit-specific answer (which is the one to use in this case), but if anyone stumbles across this question in a non-Gerrit context, here's what is going on and what you can therefore do.

When you run:

```
git clone <url>
```

(note the lack of a `-b` argument), your Git software:

1. creates a new, empty directory, in which the remaining steps run;
2. runs `git init` to create an empty *repository* (one with no commits, nothing at all in it);
3. runs `git remote add origin <url>` to save the URL under the name `origin`;
4. runs any `git config` steps called for (none are, in this case, but step 4 exists in case you add `-c` arguments);
5. runs `git fetch origin` to copy all the *commits* from the Git that responded at the given URL; and
6. runs `git checkout` or `git switch` (depending on your Git vintage) to *create one branch* in your new repository.

Note that step 5, which copies all the *commits* from the other repository, *does not copy any branches*.  Instead, it takes each of their *branch names* and *changes these names into your own remote-tracking names*.  A remote-tracking name—which Git rather misleadingly calls a "remote-tracking branch name"—is not a branch name at all.  It's just a way for *your* Git software to remember, in *your* repository, the *branch names from some other Git repository*.

After step 5 finishes, you have a repository, but you have *no branches at all yet* and *no commit is checked out yet*.  It's now time for your Git to choose a branch name to create.  Which branch name should your Git create for you?  Git's answer is: *whatever name you supplied as the `-b` option argument*.  But you didn't supply a `-b` and argument.  So your Git asks *their* Git: *Which branch name do you, other Git, recommend I use in this new repository I just made?*

Here, the other Git recommended something ridiculous—probably `refs/meta/config` as in [Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72131167/1256452).  Your Git said to itself: "This is nutty, I can't use that."  Your Git then gave up in a huff and printed:

```
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

*instead* of doing step 6.

To fix this—in a way that you control *even if you don't have access to the Gerrit server—you can either:

- provide a `-b` argument telling your Git which branch you'd like it to create when you run `git clone`, or
- after this failure, simply run `git checkout main` or `git switch main` (substitute in whatever branch name you wanted).

In other words, **this is a very mild error**.  It's just annoying.  You simply have to do *your own checkout* since `git clone` was unable to use the name *they* recommended.  **The clone has already worked!**